# undefined reference 'OpenNIProcessor::run()'

Tags: c++

I have created a header file 'OpenNIProcessor.h' and I have declared the run() method in the headerfile.

The error-message that I get is: main.cpp: undefined reference to 'OpenNIProcessor::run()'

OpenNIProcessor.h

```
class OpenNIProcessor
{
    public:
        void cloud_cb_ (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::ConstPtr &cloud);
        void run();
    protected:
    private:
};
```

OpenNIProcessor.cpp

```
class OpenNIProcessor
{
    public:
    void cloud_cb_ (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::ConstPtr &cloud)
    {
        ....
    }

    void run ()
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    OpenNIProcessor v;
    v.run();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: why do you need `class OpenNIProcessor` in OpenNIProcessor.cpp? The implementation should look like `void OpenNIProcessor::run() {...}`

Comment: because its a class, and i have several methods

Comment: yeah, but you are violating basic c++ syntax. Pls refer to @Steephen's suggestion below

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite code in  file OpenNIProcessor.cpp as follows:

```
void OpenNIProcessor::cloud_cb_ 
                  (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::ConstPtr &cloud)
    {
        ....
    }

    void OpenNIProcessor::run ()
    {
     ....
    }
```

Comment: @NerimanArif  this is the correct syntax, and your syntax is wrong, please refer a good cpp book for learning cpp

Comment: I did check the syntax ont this website: http://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/object-class

Comment: Yes, defintely you may get other errors, if you dont know what you are doing. See:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fa69c4e55c9349a

Comment: Why do you even comment out OpenNIProcessor::cloud_cb_ 
When Im using it?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca90e758c1c5d3b6 
he commented your method as it requires external dependencies such as PCL

Comment: I made all the changes for testing.  as you wrote ahmed, but Im still getting the same error. Maybee something wrong with the CMakeLists.txt

Comment: This is how my CMakeLists.txt looks like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/feecb40242e260df